# Как перевести pyrogram.types.Message в dict

Tags: python, dict, pyrogram

Я скачиваю весь чат из телеграм для анализа. Хочу сохранить все в pandas dataframe:

```
    messages = []
    for page in tqdm(range(0, app.get_history_count(selected_chat.chat_id)//100)):
        messages += app.get_history(chat_id=selected_chat.chat_id, limit=100, offset=page*100)
   
    df = pd.DataFrame(messages)
```

Но так как функция `get_history` возвращает `pyrogram.types.Message` а не `dict`, Dataframe сохраняется неправильно, как массив строк такого типа:

```
{
    "_": "Message",
    "message_id": 6467,
    "from_user": {
        "_": "User",
        "id": 8573333,
        "is_self": true,
        "is_contact": false,
        "is_mutual_contact": false,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_bot": false,
        "is_verified": false,
        "is_restricted": false,
        "is_scam": false,
        "is_fake": false,
        "is_support": false,
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "status": "offline",
        "last_online_date": "2021-04-08 17:32:28",
        "username": "pmovin",
        "dc_id": 2,
        "phone_number": "*********",
        "photo": {
            "_": "ChatPhoto",
            "small_file_id": "AQADAgADq6cxU9GzMACGeCa5cuAAMCAAPlPRszAAR1d13nexiynju_BAABHgQ",
            "small_photo_unique_id": "AQADZ4Jrly4AAzu_BAAB",
            "big_file_id": "AQADAgADq6cxG-U9GzMACGeCa5cuAAMDAAPlPRszAAR1d13nexiynj2_BAABHgQ",
            "big_photo_unique_id": "AQADZ4Jrly4AAz2_BAAB"
        }
    },
    "date": "2021-04-08 14:55:05",
    "chat": {
        "_": "Chat",
        "id": 814631267,
        "type": "private",
        "is_verified": false,
        "is_restricted": false,
        "is_scam": false,
        "is_fake": false,
        "is_support": false,
        "username": "",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "photo": {
            "_": "ChatPhoto",
            "small_file_id": "AQADAgADqqcxG2NJCBwJIJUuAAMCAANjSY4wAATK3WxlkqGwa3kGBAABHgQ",
            "small_photo_unique_id": "AQADHAkg4AA3kGBAAB",
            "big_file_id": "AQADAgADqqcxG2NJjACBwJIJUuAAMDAANjSY4wAATK3WxlkqGwa3sGBAABHgQ",
            "big_photo_unique_id": "AQADHAkg4AA3sGBAAB"
        },
        "dc_id": 2
    },
    "reply_to_message": {
        "_": "Message",
        "message_id": 6625,
        "from_user": {
            "_": "User",
            "id": ,
            "is_self": false,
            "is_contact": true,
            "is_mutual_contact": true,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "is_bot": false,
            "is_verified": false,
            "is_restricted": false,
            "is_scam": false,
            "is_fake": false,
            "is_support": false,
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "status": "online",
            "next_offline_date": "2021-04-08 17:58:08",
            "username": "",
            "dc_id": 2,
            "phone_number": "*********",
            "photo": {
                "_": "ChatPhoto"
                "small_file_id": "AQADAgADqqcxG2NJCBwJUuAAMCAANjSY4wAATK3WxlkqGwa3kGBAABHgQ",
                "small_photo_unique_id": "AQADHAlS4AA3kGBAAB",
                "big_file_id": "AQADAgADqqcxG2NJjjAAJIJUuAAMDAANjSY4wAATK3WxlkqGwa3sGBAABHgQ",
                "big_photo_unique_id": "AQADHAkglS4AA3sGBAAB"
            }
        },
        "date": "2021-04-08 14:54:50",
        "chat": {
            "_": "Chat",
            "id": 814267,
            "type": "private",
            "is_verified": false,
            "is_restricted": false,
            "is_scam": false,
            "is_fake": false,
            "is_support": false,
            "username": "",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "photo": {
                "_": "ChatPhoto",
                "small_file_id": "AQADAgADqqcG2NJjjAAIJUuAAMCAANjSY4wAATK3WxlkqGwa3kGBAABHgQ",
                "small_photo_unique_id": "AQADHAkglA3kGBAAB",
                "big_file_id": "AQADAgADqqcxG2NJACBwJIJUuAAMDAANjSY4wAATK3WxlkqGwa3sGBAABHgQ",
                "big_photo_unique_id": "AQADHAkglS3sGBAAB"
            },
            "dc_id": 2
        },
        "mentioned": false,
        "scheduled": false,
        "from_scheduled": false,
        "text": "Это",
        "outgoing": false
    },
    "mentioned": false,
    "scheduled": false,
    "from_scheduled": false,
    "text": "Сейчас",
    "outgoing": true
}
```

А я хочу что бы он разные поля сохранил в разные столбцы. Для этого я хотел сделать массив словарей, но у меня появилась проблема с переводом pyrogram.types.Message -> dict().

```
dict(message) #  return getattr(self, item) TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

Хочется как то реализовать это, не при помощи присваивания отдельных полей, так как у сообщения может быть очень много различный данных, которые могут быть очень сильно различаться (стикеры, гифки итп). Не хочется все это прописывать ручками.

Может быть ее можно сделать не переводя в словари.

Answer (score 0):

Я уже какой раз начинаю предложение с большим удивлением, но я решил просто написать код.

```
from json import loads

data: dict = loads(get_history(...))
```

Объясняю как это работает, get_history выдает ответ в формате `JSON`, следовательно мы с легкостью можем его превратить в `dict` с помощью `json.loads()`.

Comment: get_history(...) что это? нет такой встроенной функции